# Saving objects with Doctrine - selecting proper table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two Entities, `Product` and `Purchased`. I have a list of default Products stored in Db that the user can choose to buy. Once the payment is done, I want to store the selected product in `Purchased`.

This is the code I have when the payment check with Paypal returns `Verified`:

```
        $product = new Product;
        $product->setName($this->get('session')->get('name'));
        $product->setDescription($this->get('session')->get('description'));
        $product->setPrice($this->get('session')->get('price'));

        $purchased = new Purchased;
        $purchased = $product;

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $em->persist($purchased);
        $em->flush();
```

At the end I have the object saved in `Product` and not in `Purchased`, which is effectively the table I want to insert the object in.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code you have:

```
$purchased = new Purchased;
$purchased = $product;
```

At line 2 your `$purchased` becomes a `$product` instance, that's why insert into `Product` is made when you call `$em->persist($purchased);`